# NGinx $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for and real_ip_header

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have a webapp under NGinx and another frontal load balancer, something like below (x.x.x.x = IP address):

> Client(a.a.a.a) -> LB (b.b.b.b) -> NGX (c.c.c.c) -> WEBAPP (d.d.d.d)

Here is a snippet of my NGinx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from  b.b.b.b;
    real_ip_recursive on;
}
```

1. The load balancer add `X-Forwarded-For` field with client IP
   `X-Forwarded-For` = `a.a.a.a`
2. NGinx search for client real IP in `X-Forwarded-For` header by omiting LB IP (`b.b.b.b`) and change `$remote_addr` from `b.b.b.b` to `a.a.a.a` so `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr` become true (OK that's what I want !)
   BUT, NGinx also complete `X-Forwarded-For` header with `a.a.a.a` IP instead of `b.b.b.b`
3. WEBAPP receive the following headers:
   `X-Forwarded-For` = `a.a.a.a, a.a.a.a`
   `X-Real-IP` = `a.a.a.a`
   -> `X-Forwarded-For` should be `a.a.a.a, b.b.b.b`

What I need is the ability to set first `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` and then search for real IP and replace `$remote_addr` value.

Any one can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: seems like your LB is not adding itself into the header.

Comment: I don't think so, NGinx is adding itself as `a.a.a.a` (see step 3, with twice `a.a.a.a` in `X-Forwarded-For` header) instead of `b.b.b.b` because of `real_ip_header` execution before `proxy_set_header`

Comment: [Related NGinx ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2127)

Comment: Isn't the fact that `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` doesn't work for you is a hint that you're doing it wrong? Consider the [following setup](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/30691c2170d4c226a0b9a05dfe587e7b). Yeah, this way X-Forwarded-For is nothing but duplicates, but every node should trust or not trust only its immediate client (should not know about the whole chain). And every node has the real (to the extent it can be trusted) client IP in `$remote_addr`. Why would you want it the other way?

Answer (score 31):

The [`$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#variables) is equal to `$http_x_forwarded_for,$remote_addr`, and the `$remote_addr` variable will be changed when `http_realip_module` is used. So you will not get the last proxy addr in that header. Changing the order of directives won't have an effect because `nginx` configuration is declarative.

When http_realip_module is used, the [`$realip_remote_addr`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#variables) variable (`nginx >= 1.9.7`) can be used as the original `$remote_addr`. So you can set your `X-Forwarded-For` header like this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$http_x_forwarded_for, $realip_remote_addr";
```

Comment: Please give more context for your answer, why might your answer work? An answer should be clear, complete, and answer the question

Comment: Amazing, this should probably be the correct answer.

Comment: Solution workd, but isnt this a bad implementation from nginx? They should atleast tell it explicitly with the module description or better provide another variable which should have stored the client info of the nginx.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here. It's annoying, and I'm not actually sure if this is feature or bug:)

I know it's not a solution, but I've removed **real_ip_header**, and simply use **X-Forwarded-For** first ipaddress to get client's ip address wherever I need it (eg. logs).

Comment: It's a workaround :) You have to parse `X-Forwarded-For` to get the real IP, but it works. I don't know if NGinx team want the feature or if it is a bug...

Comment: If real_ip_header was removed, the $remote_addr does not get the actual client IP from X-Forwarded-For.

Answer (score 4):

I recently came across the same "problem" and came to the conclusion that this behaviour is caused by the `real_ip_recursive on;` directive.

From the [nginx realip docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html):

> If recursive search is enabled, an original client address that matches one of the trusted addresses is replaced by the last non-trusted address sent in the request header field.

You have specified to trust `b.b.b.b` (because of your `set_real_ip_from  b.b.b.b;`

So what you would expect, i.e. `a.a.a.a, b.b.b.b` will get replaced by `a.a.a.a, a.a.a.a`.

The source that made this clear for me is: https://serverfault.com/questions/314574/nginx-real-ip-header-and-x-forwarded-for-seems-wrong